# Google+ / Google Plus photo stacking , how they do this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-plus

i'm trying to develop an album photo stack like google+,
i just read all post that talk about this "problem" ... but nothing..all wrong.
I'm using Chrome and, in google+ ,i see the whole movement of the photos... in the others examples i can't see this effect, only the begin situation and the end situation.
I see that google+ append a div at the end of body, that contain the same images of the div in the page, and put it(with absolute position) over the exist div.
The new div make the movement while the old one don't!
i recreate the same situation , but don't work good, also i can see the begin and end situation.

here the html

```
<div class="cn">
    <img src="media/images/david-guetta-will-i-am.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="media/images/david-guetta--nothing-but-the-beat-11704-cropped.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="media/images/Render_BMW_Serie3_F30_01.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="media/images/david-guetta-will-i-am.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

i don't know why google+ put a copy of the first image.

and JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.cn:first').mouseenter(
function()
{
    $('body').append('<div class="cn cn2" style="z-index:5; position:absolute;">'+$(this).parent().html()+'</div>');

    $('.cn2').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.cn2 img:nth-child(1)').css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(-6deg) translate(-40px,0) scale(1.05)'});
        $('.cn2 img:nth-child(2)').css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(0deg) translate(0,0) scale(1.05)'});
        $('.cn2 img:nth-child(3)').css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(6deg) translate(40px,0) scale(1.05)'});
    });
    $('.cn2').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $('.cn2 img:nth-child(1),.cn2 img:nth-child(2),.cn2 img:nth-child(3)').css({'-webkit-transform':'none'});
    });

});
</script>
```

here the code run in jdFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eUVNH/22/

Comment: can't you, using http://www.jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net/ gives us a live example?

Comment: yes .. http://jsfiddle.net/eUVNH/22/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you probably would use `$().animate` instead of `.css()`

Comment: ok, sry...you have to add -webkit-transition to your css [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUVNH/45/)